# Como 'quebrar' um texto a cada intervalo de caracteres - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Gostaria de saber como se 'quebra'(função split) um texto a cada 8 caracteres no javascript por exemplo:

```
var teste = '1234567898'
teste.split({a cada 8 caracteres})
//retorna ['12345678', '898'];
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução fazendo uso do método [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) com uma expressão regular:

```js
var teste = '1234567898';

alert(teste.match(/.{1,8}/g));        // Devolve: 12345678,98
console.log(teste.match(/.{1,8}/g));  // Devolve: ["12345678", "98"]
```

Comment: Esta expressão possui erros, pois, por exemplo, a string `123456789123` retornaria `["12345678", "12", "3"]`, no entanto, a expressão `/.{1,8}/g` irá retornar o resultado desejado.

Comment: @Oeslei Obrigado pelo alerta, estava a fazer testes e a editar, já simplifiquei e corrigi.

Comment: Muito obrigado a expressão /.{1,8}/g funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu XD

Answer (score 3):

```js
var texto = "x2345678y2345678z23";
var dist = 8;
var resultado = new Array(parseInt(texto.length / dist));
for (var x = 0; x < texto.length / dist; x++) {
    resultado[x] = texto.substring(0 + x * dist, (x + 1) * dist);
}
document.write(resultado);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @old7 essa é sem duvida um opção quando a repressão regular por algum motivo não for permitida, Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar como contribuição o *port* da função [str_split()](http://www.php.net/str_split) do PHP para JavaScript feita pelo pessoal do [PHPJS.org](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_split/)

```js
function str_split(string, split_length) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/str_split/
  // original by: Martijn Wieringa
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  //  revised by: Theriault
  //  revised by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl/)
  //    input by: Bjorn Roesbeke (http://www.bjornroesbeke.be/)
  //   example 1: str_split('Hello Friend', 3);
  //   returns 1: ['Hel', 'lo ', 'Fri', 'end']

  if (split_length === null) {
    split_length = 1;
  }
  if (string === null || split_length < 1) {
    return false;
  }
  string += '';
  var chunks = [],
    pos = 0,
    len = string.length;
  while (pos < len) {
    chunks.push(string.slice(pos, pos += split_length));
  }

  return chunks;
}

console.log( str_split( '1234567898', 8 ) );
```

O resultado é o mesmo: Um array de dois índices sendo o primeiro composto pela *substring* 12345678 e o segundo pela *substring* 98.